# Force between two current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

Is the force which acts perpendicular to a wire due to another current wire in its vicinity consistent or it is just for a brief time? I thought it should be for a brief time because only for a moment all electrons will drift in the direction of force but after that the force will change its direction (it has to be perpendicular to velocity always, right?) 
Further, does this force do work on the wire? (Caveat: Kindly keep in mind while answering that I'm just a 12th grader and I know nothing of quantum mechanics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forces do not always induce motion.  Instead, they can be counteracted by other forces.

In this case, we can clamp the wires into a form.  Any force created by the current is counteracted by the form, so the wires don't move.  Steady current, static wires, constant force.

Since there is no motion in this case, there is no work done.

You are correct that if we allow the charges to move arbitrarily (rather than forcing them to remain on a wire that is fixed in place), then the situation would be much more complex.